# Validate and Change value from list of object using Lambda java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
Mood Pojo (nameOfMood, Score, Category)
Mood happyMood = new Mood("Happy", 10, POSITIVE);
Mood sadMood = new Mood("Sad", 1, NEGATIVE);
Mood confusedMood = new Mood("Confused", 6, NEGATIVE);
Mood irritatedMood = new Mood("Irritated", 5, NEGATIVE);
Mood blessedMood = new Mood("Blessed", 10, POSITIVE);
```

Check if the score is great than 5, update the category value to positive and fetch all the positive category mood to a `Map<String(nameOfMood), Mood>` using single line lambda or stream funcion

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there will not be a positive Mood for score < 5 for sure. else you should add those with score less than 5 to this list.

```java
List<Mood> mood = Arrays.asList(happyMood, sadMood, ...);
Map<String(nameOfMood), Mood> result =  mood.stream()
              .filter(e-> e.getScore() > 5)
              .peek(e-> e.setCategory("Positive"))
              .map(Collectors.toMap(e->e.nameOfMood(), e));
```

Comment: Why would you create List then transform it to Stream? Can't you use Stream.of? Also, peek is mainly for debugging purposes, check javadoc.

Comment: Thanks, Stream.of can directly be used instead of creating List.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Mood` has full-args constructor and `Category` is an enum, this is what are you looking for:

```
Map<String, Mood> map = Stream.of(happyMood, sadMood, confusedMood, irritatedMood, blessedMood)
    .filter(mood -> mood.getScore() > 5 || POSITIVE == mood.getCategory())
    .map(mood -> new Mood(mood.getNameOfMood(), mood.getScore(), POSITIVE))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Mood::getNameOfMood, Function.identity()));
```

There are 4 simple steps:

1. Using the advantage of `Stream::of` to stream over *n* of inputs of the same type.
2. Using `Stream::filter` to keep these that are either `POSITIVE` or have `score > 5` (since these are about to become `POSITIVE` in the next step.
3. Using `Stream::map` to turn each reamining mood to `POSITIVE`.
4. Using `Stream::collect` to pack the stream into a desired output defined with the collector `Collectors.toMap(Mood::getNameOfMood, Function.identity())`, which creates a map with keys of `nameOfMood` and values the object `Mood` itself.

Just be careful, this solution doesn't work for the objects with duplicated `nameOfMood` since the `Map` cannot contain duplicated keys. If you wish to keep all the values, you have to either use grouping resulting in `Map<String, List<Mood>>` or perform a further reduction to achieve the original desired result `Map<String, Mood>`.